# How do I parse JSON from a String using serde?

Tags: rust

I tried this

```rust
let tags = serde_json::from_str("['java']")
```

but it returns `Error("expected value", line: 1, column: 2)'`.

Comment: that's not valid json, json uses `"` (double quotes) not `'` (single quotes) for strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like kmdreko said in the comments, the reason is that JSON uses double-quotes instead of single-quotes for strings and keys. Because Rust uses double-quotes for strings you have to either escape the inner double-quote or use a raw string literal.

```
// Escaped double-quotes
let json: Vec<String> = serde_json::from_str("[ \"tags\" ]")
    .expect("Failed to parse json.");
assert!(json.len() == 1)

// Raw string literal
let json: Vec<String> = serde_json::from_str(r#"[ "tags" ] "#)
    .expect("Failed to parse json.");
assert!(json.len() == 1)
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6cf05e6c26044ca800e6bb8695cac7e9)